# add a header on top of the page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, ieeetran

I just want to add a simple text on top all (or the first) pages stating "FOR AUTHOR ONLY". However, I found it not very clear how to add that!

Here is the code which I borrow from this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50492/adding-header-and-footer-to-the-front-page-and-other-pages-of-an-article)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, lipsum}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[C]{FOR AUTHOR ONLY}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\title{Something}
\end{document}
```

Problem with that is it will add the text in the **bottom** of all pages **expect** the first page.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\fancyhead` and not `\fancyfoot` if you want it in the header.

Also, if you want it only for the first page, define a new style, let's say `mahmood`

```
\fancypagestyle{mahmood}{%
   \fancyhf{} % clear all fields
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \fancyhead[C]{FOR AUTHOR ONLY}
}%
```

and issue

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@mahmood
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mahmood}{%
   \fancyhf{} % clear all fields
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \fancyhead[C]{FOR AUTHOR ONLY}
}%

\makeatletter
\let\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@mahmood
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Something}
\author{mahmood}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want it for all pages, add

```
\pagestyle{mahmood}
```

at the beginning of the document.